# How to make an avi that sequentially fills a square?

Tags: matlab, avi

I want to make like this:

[image: I want to make like this]

First, I wrote a code to divide room:

```
close all;
figure;hold on;

plot([0,8],[0,0],'black');
plot([0,8],[8,8],'black');
plot([0,0],[0,8],'black');
plot([8,8],[0,8],'black');
plot([2,2],[0,8],'black');
plot([4,4],[0,8],'black');
plot([6,6],[0,8],'black');
plot([3,3],[0,8],'red');
plot([5,5],[0,8],'red');
plot([0,8],[2,2],'black');
plot([0,8],[4,4],'black');
plot([0,8],[6,6],'black');
plot([0,8],[3,3],'red');
plot([0,8],[5,5],'red');

axis equal;

xlim([-1,9])
ylim([-1,9])
set(gca,'xtick',[-1:1:9]) 
set(gca,'ytick',[-1:1:9])
```

But I don't know what to do next to make my code like that gif (actuallyavi).
   Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in a loop (with different position values (x,y,w and h) to create the moving blocks you want.

```
% draw rectangle at position [x y w h] with Facecolour Red
rectangle('Position',[0 0 2 2],'FaceColor',[1 0 0])
```

Export/save all the figures after they are formed Then maybe you can use the VideoWriter function to create an avi file out of that.